# Is there a way to prevent R from changing my variables to serial numbers in PCA analysis?

Tags: r, pca

I am running a PCA analysis using the FactoMineR and factoextra packages in R. After the analysis, R keeps changing my first column which are the row names into serial numbers. I want to know how to retain the column as it is without it being changed to serial numbers.

I'm new to R so i don't know how to go about this.

```
library(readr)
library(FactoMineR)
mm <- read_csv("masters.csv")
mm.active$TREATMENTS <- as.factor(mm.active$TREATMENTS) #this the column 
#that is being changed to serial number
mm.active <- mm[1:36, 2:12] #to specify the active components
head(mm.active[ , 1:6])
res.pca <- PCA(mm.active, graph = FALSE)
print(res.pca)
plot(res.pca, choix = "var") #this displays the PCA plot of the variables
plot(res.pca, choix = "ind") #this is supposed to show that of the 
# "TREATMENTS" column showing each treatments but it shows serial numbers 
#instead
```

I expect to see each of the treatments being shown on the plot but R is showing serial numbers instead.

Comment: Just a reminder, PCA works only for numerical values.

Comment: Yes, i know but i need the treatments to be represented as they are in the data with their names and not with serial numbers. Is there a way i can do this?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO! I do not have your data, so here an example with the famous `mtcars` dataset:

```
library(FactoMineR)
res.pca <- PCA(mtcars, graph = FALSE)
plot(res.pca, choix = "ind")
```

[image]

It's printing the cars' name because they're rownames. So, you've to remove the `TREATMENTS` from your data, and add them as rownames (or viceversa, like my code, due I've imagined you've right now that column in your dataset):

```
rownames(mm.active) <- mm.active$TREATMENTS
mm.active[ , -which(names(mm.active) %in% c("TREATMENTS"))]
```

And then run PCA.